# Find the turning point of $y=x^2(2-x^2)$ and determine if it it is a max or min point.

Tags: calculus

After differentiating I got $4x-4x^3$ ....how are we supposed to get the answer when the its $x^3$??? I'm kinda lost here! >.<

EDIT: Sorry Kasper, I googled that Math app you told me to it's not free however. I tried my best to get the $x^2$ and the $x^3$ symbol. I truly apologize for the inconvenience but I'm not good in typing maths formula out in the computer.

If anyone can help, please suggest me an online website that can do the math equation easily to avoid confusion.

Comment: I was talking about MathJax, that is absolutely free, and you can use it on the website by placing dollars \$...\$ around the math. I've edited your post.

Comment: @Kasper let me give it a try... $y=x^2(2-x^2)$

Comment: Wow gee! Though I'm not supposed to say the word "thank you" here but please let me say it... Thank you! At least I can now improve myself in maths equation

Comment: But is the (money symbol) .... (money symbol) code applicable to only this website?

Comment: Consider factoring out an $4x$ from your derivative calculation; that should simplify to a much simpler quadratic.

Comment: @Jamil_V but that doesn't make me get the $ax^2+bx+c=0$ ! >.< I mean by that equation, you will get two $x$ answers...

Comment: It should give you a quadratic equation with the $b$ term equal to 0 after factoring; i.e., $4x(1-x^2)$. As the answer posted mentions, you will have three points to check.

Comment: @Jamil_V .okay so how are we supposed to type these numbers ( 4x−4x3=0 ) in the calculator? I mean the equation part. Are we using the let x be 1,2,3 method???

Comment: Well, we would have the equation $4x(1-x^2)=0$. Personally, I don't think a calculator is needed in this case because we have three possibilities: $4x=0 \Rightarrow x=0$, or $1-x^2=0 \Rightarrow x= \pm 1$. These in turn are your critical points which can help you determine the max/mix of the function.

Comment: @Jamil_V Oh gee! I never noticed! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @YamadaYousuke You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, keep going. To find turning points, set $y'$ equal to zero, factor the differential equation ($4x-4x^3$) and you should be able to determine the turning points (there are three of them). Check each case to see if they are a maximum or minimum.

Comment: In order to determine the 3 points, are we using the "Let $x=1,2,3$ ??

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. Setting $y'=0$ we find

$4x-4x^3=0$

which implies

$4x(1-x^2)=0$

Can you solve for $x$ now?

Comment: It doesn't matter sir...okay so how are we supposed to type these numbers ( $4x−4x^3=0$ ) in the calculator? I mean the equation part